# iTextSharp and ZUGFeRD Basic profile

Tags: itext

I am creating ZUGFeRD PDF files with iTextSharp 5.5.9 which works fine so far. The only thing which is currently not working is the setting with the Conformance-Level.

```
writer = PdfAWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(strFilenameOut, FileMode.Create), PdfAConformanceLevel.ZUGFeRDBasic)
```

or

```
writer.SetPDFXConformance(PdfAConformanceLevel.ZUGFeRDBasic)
```

won't work for me. The Metadata contains %s instead of BASIC as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: ZUGFeRD Metadata]

I guess that I missed something to set. Maybe someone had the same issue and can help me to solve this issue.

Regards
Jochen

Answer (score 0):

ZUGFeRD is based on the PDF/A-3 standard. You are using a method to set PDF/X conformance. PDF/A and PDF/X are two very different standards. You shouldn't set the PDF/X conformance.

Please take a look at the official documentation. I have written a book about ZUGFeRD. You can download this book as an eBook if you fill out this form: http://pages.itextpdf.com/ZUGFeRD.html

For the Basic profile, you need to take a look at [Chapter 5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/5-creating-pdf-invoices-basic-profile). There are [many examples available online](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/zugferd).

This is how it's done in Java:

```
PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document,
    new FileOutputStream(dest), PdfAConformanceLevel.ZUGFeRDBasic);
```

In C#, you'll have:

```
PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.GetInstance(document,
    New FileStream(strFilenameOut, FileMode.Create), PdfAConformanceLevel.ZUGFeRDBasic)
```

All the examples work in Java, but recently there was a problem detected with the C# port. Maybe you are experiencing the same problem. As far as I know, this problem has been fixed in the current development version.

If you are a customer, you should ask your account manager to get a hotfix that solves this problem.

Comment: Hello Bruno,
it's me again. I am using iText# in 5.5.8 and have the same error by using PdfACopy. I am instantiating PdfACopy this way `PdfACopy copy = new PdfACopy(docZUGFeRD, fs, PdfAConformanceLevel.ZUGFeRDBasic);`. I identified that the replace-function (String.Format) doesn't work at all. It just doesn't replace the `%s`. I added some screenshots to the post to illustrate what i mean. @Jochen, how did you solve this problem?

Comment: Does the problem persist in iTextSharp 5.5.9?

Comment: I just updated to 5.5.9 and the problem still exists

Comment: Than you should file a ticket with customer support at iText Software.

Comment: Well, I am not a customer so far, so I think I cannot open a ticket, right?